# Yajra DataTables Search Not Working for Modified Column

Tags: laravel, datatable, server-side, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra DataTables in Laravel and experiencing issues with the search functionality for the modefied column (HAWB). I've modified the HAWB column definition to display a clickable link, but searching on the actual HAWB value isn't working.

```
return DataTables::of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('HAWB', function ($row) {
        $url = route('shipment_tracking') . "?trknbr=" . $row->HAWB;
        return "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$row->HAWB</a>";
    })
    ->rawColumns(['HAWB'])
    ->make(true);
```

`   $('#airwaybill-tracking').DataTable({
pageLength: 10,
processing: true,
serverSide: true,

```
    ajax: route.admin_dashboard,
    columns: [,
        {
            data: 'HAWB',
            name: 'HAWB',
            className: 'text-sm',
        },
     ]`
});
```

I'm using Laravel with Yajra DataTables package
I'm using server-side processing

**What I've Tried:**

I've verified the route configuration for route('shipment_tracking').
I've used console logs to check the search term and generated URL.
I've tried temporarily disabling other column definitions to isolate conflicts.

**Expected Behavior:**
Users should be able to search for HAWB numbers, even though the column displays a link.

**Actual Behavior:**
Searching doesn't seem to work correctly for the HAWB column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your Controller Code:

```
return DataTables::of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->editColumn('HAWB', function ($row) {
        $url = route('shipment_tracking') . "?trknbr=" . $row->HAWB;
        return "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$row->HAWB</a>";
    })
    ->rawColumns(['HAWB'])
    ->make(true);
```

In then inspite of `addColumn` use `editColumn` then you will also be able to search that field